# User login and authentication on a Express JS web app

Tags: node.js, express, session, parse-platform

I am new to Node JS and Express JS.

I am developing a simple Express JS web app, which requires user login and authentication. The web app sends a http POST to a separate backend Parse server for user authentication where users are stored along with a session-token string associated (generated by the Parse server when user is logged in).

When authentication is successful, the Parse server will return a valid session-token string to the Express JS web app and the user will be directed to the home page of the web app. Other pages of the web app will be accessible until the user logs out.

My question is where the authenticated user should be stored on the web app server side. Where can I use the session (if supported by Node JS) to store session scoped objects? What are the modules that can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

**1, Where the authenticated user should be stored on the web app server side.**

Express store your user info in req.user

**2, Where can I use the session (if supported by Node JS) to store session scoped objects?**

You can store session in memory or in caching DB (redis) or create a session collection on your DB

**3, What are the modules that can be used to achieve this?**

Common modules for session store and authentication in Nodejs is [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) .